# PWA Angular router.navigate'['/], { queryParams: { id: id} }] with query params is not working IOS devices

Tags: ios, angular, iphone, progressive-web-apps

I have developed a PWA angular app for mobile, the angular router with query params is working fine in android phones but not working in IOS phones.
** this.router.navigate(['/abc'], { queryParams: { id: id} });
**

Answer (score 0):

Can you share any errors you are getting for the path match?
Also, you can try the following instead.

`this.router.navigateByUrl('abc');`

For maintaining a previous router

`this.router.navigate(['/logout',{routeFrom: this.router.url}]);`

Comment: no errots redirect is not working

Answer (score 0):

What is `id: id`? If it's a string wrap the left id in quotes. If it's a variable add `this.` up front. Also I think the dash `/` is not necessary on url.

```js
 this.router.navigate(['abc'], { queryParams: { id: 'id'} })
```

Here is an example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-navigate-with-query-params-dup5cg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

From my example as template url.

```html
<a [routerLink]="['/authenticate']" [queryParams]="{ jwt: 'myID'}">Authenticate</a> | <a routerLink="/home">Home</a> |
```

And using `navigate()`

```js
//html
<button (click)="navigate()">Navigate to Authenticate</button>

constructor(private router: Router) {}

navigate() {
    this.router.navigate( ['authenticate'], { queryParams: { jwt: 'myID'}});
}
```